# MPI_Comm_spawn: Are the new processes created sequentially or all at the same time?

Tags: c, fortran, mpi

I want to know if the **MPI_Comm_spawn** operation creates the number of processes indicated sequentially (e.g. one after another) or simultaneously. I am using MPICH implementation.

I'm working on a code that performs malleability at a process level, and I want to know how this operation performs the processes creation (to understand if the overhead depends on more parameters, like the number of processes and how they are created). I can't find information about it. Maybe someone with more experience knows it.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't use MPI dynamic process creation, so I don't count myself an expert, but it would be unusual for the MPI standard to specify the implementation in such detail - certainly as I read the entry for `MPI_Comm_spawn` in https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-4.0/mpi40-report.pdf I can see nothing that requires either of the methods you mention. It is possible there is text elsewhere within the standard that defines what you want, but I would be surprised. In summary I would assume the behaviour is implementation dependent.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. What do you mean by "at the same time"? Initiated from different threads of the original process? I also do not think it is specified, but you can always study the code of some specific implementations.

Comment: I expect this to depend on both the MPI library you are using and the environment such as a resource manager if any.

Comment: @IanBush I have already read that report, but it includes common explanations and an example. I miss something with more detail. Thanks

Comment: @Vladimir Thaks to suggest me the tour. "at the same time" refers to the implementation when a process calls the function. I do not know if the spawn is done by groups of processes or they are created one after one (loop). I'm going to study the MPICH code, as you say. I wanted to avoid that :(  Thanks.

Comment: @Gilles It seems it depends on the implementation because the resource manager (if it exists) allocates the resources before this call. I'm going to study the MPICH code. Thanks

Comment: Last thing I will say as I am not an expert in this, but if it were me I would desperately try to avoid anything that is implementation specific - I would very much try to find another way to solve the problem that fits in with what the standard guarantees. My own experience tells me that the implementation I most commonly use will change with time, and even that the behaviour of a given implementation may be different with a new release. Stick to what the standard ensure and you will be safe.

Comment: @IanBush Thanks a lot. I agree with you. However, I am working on I+D, and sometimes we have to develop solutions ad-hoc.

Comment: Are you spawning a MPI application? if so, spawning an other process is only the first step. The second step is to wire-up the MPI layer. Both steps are likely to require different amount of time, and might not scale in the same way.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes. Before the spawn, we estimate the data that each process (including both initial and dynamic) should compute, and after the spawn, we redistribute them. The load is balanced in our case.